# How to associate Windows Photo Viewer without the fullscreen parameter?

Tags: windows

So I'm making a .bat to associate image files back to Windows Photo Viewer, the only way I got it to work is with this command:

```
ftype jpegfile=%SystemRoot%\System32\rundll32.exe "%ProgramFiles%\Windows Photo Viewer\PhotoViewer.dll", ImageView_Fullscreen %1
```

But it opens the image in full screen. I want to open it windowed.
What is the parameter for photoviewer to open it windowed?

Comment: I'm presuming you tried ImageView_Windowed ?

Comment: I did, didn't work..
I also tried searching for a list of parameters, didn't find any

Answer (score 0):

There is only these export functions available in PhotoViewer.dll. You can not open images with any other function. View with [DLL Export Viewer](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html).

`DllCanUnloadNow
DllGetClassObject
DllRegisterServer
DllUnregisterServer
ImageView_COMServerW
ImageView_FullscreenW
imageview_fullscreenW`